# When do we consider English speakers' familiarity as a proof?

Tags: word-usage, non-native-english

English, like many other languages, has its own *usage of words* and *convention* that can only be captured by practicing and speaking with natives. For instance, if a non-English-speaker comes up with a grammatically correct sentence, that doesn't always mean it is correct.

So, in which cases do we accept answers that indicate *familiarity* or *unfamiliarity* of certain word usage from English speakers as a **supporting argument** or a **proof**?

Comment: Sorry, but a supporting argument or proof of *what*?

Comment: +1 DeepYellow though I ran out of comment-votes.

Comment: I understand your first paragraph, but not your second.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase it here, can we take an English speaker familiarity as a proof of how correct a certain phrase is used?

Comment: Answers in this forum should be supported by reputable evidence, not merely: "I am a native speaker and that's how I always do it."

Comment: Seems like this question would be more appropriate for [meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As the question is asking how we accept answers, I say it definitively is a question for meta.

Comment: @GEdgar _Nein_ forum, _nein_!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Meta.

Comment: Respected dictionaries and grammars inspect data to decide how words and constructions are actually used, and have panels voting on acceptability. These must almost always trump individual views (though grey areas exist where these authorities can't agree).

Comment: Many questions on the site are answered with Ngrams, indicating only popularity.  People have made attempts to formalize the language and record or abstract rules for it.  Ultimately, the language is how speakers use it.  When something becomes commonplace, it gets incorporated into the formal rules.  Often, the question isn't so much "is this right?", as "is this common enough to be currently recognized in some reputable source?".  Native speakers can attest to how the language is currently used in their location.  That may or may not be universal practice (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jamie, looking at your comment below your question, which clarifies your question, the answer would be no not for certain.

An English speaker might be rather familiar with a phrase, and the English speaker might use it regularly, as well knowing other people who also use it, but that doesn't give conclusive proof as to the correctness of a phrase. The factors that affect this include the fact that the phrase might be used in a certain way that as peculiar to the region from which the English speaker came from, and not necessarily applicable to the rest of the world. Also, the "other people" that the English speaker knows might be restricted to his friends and family, who could possibly have been influenced by himself( quite possible).

So, no, not for certain. Just because a native English speaker says he knows it quite well, is not proof for the correctness of a phrase. Without the evidence of a conclusive agreement by the world on such a phrase (such as dictionaries, etymologies, or links), just an opinion is not enough.

Comment: I believe that you've answered my question and other related matters. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

When you're trying to describe how native speakers use language, evidence that particular native speakers do or don't use language a particular way is exactly the best kind of evidence you can have.

Comment: Great, then if I may ask another related question, can we put a native speaker way in importance level as other references like (Idiom dictionaries, Ngrams ...etc) ?

Comment: These other references you mention measure the same thing, how native speakers use the language. Generally these measures are more useful than asking an individual speaker because they summarize observations of large numbers of native speakers.

Answer (score 3):

Most Americans are native speakers of English. Let me tell you: as a group, we are completely untrustworthy on matters of spelling, grammar, and usage. We make so many crazy mistakes that [cataloging the best ones](http://chriswrites.net/2011/03/14/for-all-intensive-purposes/) makes good sport. And it looks like Americans [aren't alone](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/4799157/Damp-Squid-The-top-10-misquoted-phrases-in-Britain.html). Non-native speakers may not have the same ear for what seems right and what doesn't, but in some cases that may be an advantage.

Comment: The ear often does work -- a native speaker in any language will often know the right answer but not the reason for it.

Comment: Re-reading my previous comment, it occurs to me that the "ear" is probably the culprit in a lot of mistakes that natives speakers make (again, applies to any language). We hear a phrase or formulation several times and come to understand what it means from the context in which it's used, but fail to understand *why* it means what it does. The result is millions of people who use "I could care less" when what they really mean is "I couldn't care less."

Answer (score 0):

I think an appeal to a native speaker's familiary with the language as authoritative should only be used as evidence against the veracity of certain assertations in which the former's rebuttal call into question the expertise of the challenged.

Comment: Speak English, please.

Answer (score -1):

To me, this is indicative of a parent saying "Because I told you so", just because they're older... More exposure to a language is never a qualification... An English PHD might have authority in English, but that hardly means they are correct only because of it.  This question seems far to general for a real answer and for that I think it should be moved to a community wiki.

Aside from that, I would contend that English subtly changes through the years... English today is English not because any authority said it was so, but because enough people started using it.  I would make a case that [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends) is a more authoritative source of grammatical correctness than an English PHD because of it's ability to represent trends and popular usages.